# SQL Query Using Cursor and table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Input table is having data and result table should read all the data from input table and check the length of Name column and should print the length which is <=5 in result table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZMxK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht5gj.png)

can you please suggest using loops (IF else) ...like reading the data using conditions i.e. <=5, and by insert statement storing it in a temporary table variable and by using final select statement we are getting the output... plz help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend taking the [tour], then reading [ask] and what a [mcve] is. Then post your question including as much detail as you can, including what code you have tried, what the specific problem you are having is, example data (as text, not an image) and the required output.

Comment: There is nothing to do with `cursor` so, i have removed incompatible tag.

Comment: Seems like you people have got an assignment to do. You are the second guy who is adamant to use the cursor for their simple operations

Answer (score 1):

Just use `LEN()` function with `case` expression :

```
select t.id,
       (case when len(name) <= 5 
             then concat(name, '_', len(name)) 
             else name 
        end) as name,
       age
from table t
```

Comment: can you please suggest using loops (IF else) ...like reading the data using conditions i.e. <=5, and by insert statement storing it in a temporary table variable and by using final select statement we are getting the output... plz help

Comment: @PrasadSatpute. . .  This is more efficient way than `loop` & why you need `loop` instead ?

Comment: ..Actually i want to try this problem statement with loop, for knowledge purpose

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try below -

```
    insert into Output_table(id,Name,Age)
    select i.id,
    (case when LEN(Name)<=5 then name+'_'+ CONVERT(varchar(2),LEN(Name))
    else Name
    end) as Name,
    i.age
    from input_table i
```

Comment: can you please suggest using loops (IF else) ...like reading the data using conditions i.e. <=5, and by insert statement storing it in a temporary table variable and by using final select statement we are getting the output... plz help

Comment: You want to write cursor for that? But why you would want to do that. It will take more time and resource. Secondly if the table is big you may experience performance problem. so I would like to understand why you would like to do cursor? @PrasadSatpute